# Is it possible to create pitch diagram in real time with TarsosDSP in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, audio, dart, visualization, tarsosdsp

Or is there are any better way to do it?

https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP

https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2019-07-drawing-waveforms-in-flutter/

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: It is possible. TarsosDSP have functions to handles pitch tracking. After building some message tunnels between Dart and Flutter, it worked. Though, I only figured out how to contruct that on Android, but not iOS.

Comment: Challenging work! How do you plan to support the multitude of jar-java files?